# Boot an existing GNU/Linux installation from a real HDD in Qemu-Windows

Tags: qemu

I'm now running windows 8 and I installed qemu-windows 1.3.1. I have two hard disks. When I try to boot existing Arch GNU/Linux from second disk using the command:

```
qemu-system-x86-64w -hda \Device\HarddiskVolume6
```

I got this error :

```
qemu-system-x86_64w.exe: -hda \Device\HarddiskVolume6: 
could not open disk image \Device\HarddiskVolume6: Invalid argument
```

Can anyone tell me why? Do I need to mount a linux partition in windows?

The bottom line is:

How do I boot an existing GNU/Linux installation from a hard disk?

### update

When I use (either of) the commands suggested by Ярослав Рахматуллин in his answer

```
qemu-system-x86_64w.exe: -hda \\.\PhysicalDrive0
qemu-system-x86_64w.exe: \\.\PhysicalDrive0
```

I get this error :

```
qemu: PC system firmware (pflash) must be a multiple of 0x1000
```

Comment: I don't understand the pflash-error. try the "full" guide that is linked in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your argument is invalid, i.e wrong. The qemu-doc.html from the qemu-windows official page/distribution states how to specify
physical hard drives in section [3.6.7.2 Windows](https://web.archive.org/web/20160303203844/http://qemu.weilnetz.de/qemu-doc.html#host_005fdrives):

```
Hard disks
    Hard disks can be used with the syntax: \\.\PhysicalDriveN where N is the 
    drive number (0 is the first hard disk). /dev/hda is supported as an alias
    to the first hard disk drive \\.\PhysicalDrive0.

    WARNING: unless you know what you do, it is better to only make READ-ONLY 
    accesses to the hard disk otherwise you may corrupt your host data (use
    the -snapshot command line so that the modifications are written in a 
    temporary file).
```

If still in doubt; read this guide: [Use physical harddisk in Virtual Box](https://superuser.com/questions/495025/use-physical-harddisk-in-virtual-box)