# How to install windows (using Linux) without cd/pendrive?

Tags: linux

I have the ISO of windows 10, but I had problem with my pendrive and it does not appear anywhere (gparted, lsusb, lshw, lsblk), and now I have no media to install windows for BOOT and install.

Is it possible to install Windows ISO on some partition, without having to boot using cd or pendrive?

Comment: AFH you can send me another one that I will use with all pleasure

Comment: Why don't you buy one? A 16GB pen-drive costs less than the postage, and a fraction of the cost of a Windows licence.

Comment: This is related : https://superuser.com/questions/495025/use-physical-harddisk-in-virtual-box