# Run existing OS installation in a virtual machine

Tags: windows, ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine, vmware

I'm running Ubuntu and Windows 10 (on different drive partitions) with dualboot on my computer.

Sometimes I would like to use a tool that is installed in Ubuntu, while I'm using Windows, without restarting the computer and booting to Ubuntu.

I know that I could install a Ubuntu VM on my computer, but I don't want two different Ubuntu insallations on my computer.

Is it possible to access the existing Ubuntu installation with a VM software (VMware, VirtualBox,..)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use physical harddisk in Virtual Box](https://superuser.com/questions/495025/use-physical-harddisk-in-virtual-box)

Comment: Do you still need the ability to dual-boot to Ubuntu? (And if so, out of curiosity, why?)

Comment: The simplest would be to install Ubuntu from the [Microsoft Store](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/ubuntu/9nblggh4msv6#activetab=pivot:overviewtab) and have both always available.

Answer (score 1):

This is posible with **VirtualBox**.

1. Create vmdk drives that read from real drives
2. Assign the vmdk drives to a VM
3. Set one of the Writethrough modes.
4. Reorder boot-priority (semi optional)

[This](https://superuser.com/questions/495025/use-physical-harddisk-in-virtual-box) or [this](https://www.serverwatch.com/server-tutorials/using-a-physical-hard-drive-with-a-virtualbox-vm.html) may help you