# Create VirtualBox Ubuntu VM from physical drive within Windows

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine

One desktop of mine has 2 physical drives; one has Windows 10 (240GB), the other has Ubuntu 18.04 (128GB).

Due to the age of the Ubuntu 18.04 disk, I am wondering if there is a way when I am booted into the Windows 10 disk that I can create a VM (via Virtualbox, or VMWare if need-be) using what is on the physical Ubuntu disk?

I see that you can use Disk2VHD when creating a Windows VM, not sure if that can be used when setting up a Ubuntu VM?

I've seen one post (somewhere) where you can use Clonezilla to create an ISO of the image. Create a VM (with no OS). Boot the VM but get into the boot-options to load Clonezilla live and then run the recovery wizard.

Though I was hoping to be able to avoid booting into Clonezilla and find a way I could do this all from the Windows 10 disk.

Comment: You can directly use a whole drive or some partition(s) of the physical drive and mount them into a VirtualBox without creating an image of it. AFAIK it only works using the command-line tools of VirtualBox. See the answers of this question: [Use physical harddisk in Virtual Box](https://superuser.com/questions/495025/use-physical-harddisk-in-virtual-box)

Comment: Why not use Timeshift to create a backup of your Ubuntu disk. Then, create the Ubuntu VM, in it install Ubuntu 18.04, install Timeshift, then restore from the backup? Haven't tried this, but I don't see why it wouldn't work.