# Boot into physical usb running it in a VM

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine

I recently installed Arch linux in a USB and was successfully able to boot into it.

I wanted to run it inside a virtual machine. Instead of using the whole computer to run the arch installation in usb, im trying to run Ubuntu on the computer and using VirtualBox or any other software to run the arch installation in.

All the i was able to find onlin were about creating a image of the usb and boot into that, which i dont want.

Is there any other software or any option in VirtualBox to boot into the physical USB ?

Comment: You just had the wrong key words to search for an answer. Search for Virtualbox raw device hdd. If you do so you may end up here: https://superuser.com/questions/495025/use-physical-harddisk-in-virtual-box

Comment: So.. what @Robert is pointing out is that no, you can't simply pick a USB device in the virtual machine (like you can with an ISO) but you CAN setup a tiny disk image that knows how to boot from USB going through all of the steps in his referenced link.  You might also be able to setup an ISO like you did the USB disk and skip those other steps.

Comment: Thanks. I was indeed using the wrong keywords. Now got the solution i was looking for !