# Virtualization Plus Dual Boot

Tags: virtualization, grub2

## tl;dr

Is it possible to run a Linux as a VM guest on top of Windows, where the Linux and Windows are dual-boot (grub) "siblings" so to say?

### Why?

Sorry if this seems unnecessarily hairy. Justification is as follows:

I am a teacher of programming etc;
Much prefer to teach from Linux than from Windows.

HOWEVER!!...

Zoom is not negotiable nowadays; I must teach over zoom.
And **Zoom-Linux invariably crashes in the middle of my classes** (typically when I am trying to change screens I am sharing)

### What

So I am wondering if I can run Zoom from Windows and for the rest live inside Linux...
As follows:

So right now

- Linux root is `/dev/nvme0n1p4` — short `p4` — on `/`
- `p6` on `/home`
- ... some others
- `p1` on `/boot/efi`

At the same time:

- `p2` is Microsoft reserved
- `p3` is the Windows `C:` — both unmounted in Linux

### Configuration I want

- Boot Windows (`p3`)
- Have a VM running in Windows
- Run the Linux on `p4` on that VM

This way then:

- Normal mode of use: Switch on machine, choose Linux at grub; use as usual
- Zoom class mode of use: Switch on machine; choose windows; start zoom; start VM (pointing to p4 Linux)

#### Personal Note

- I've used some kind or other of *nix for 35 years.
- Never used VMs though I saw some of my students using Linux inside them
- Its a headache setting up Haskell, Python, Gcc etc under Windows...
- But zoom is crashing so relentlessly that if (something like) the above is not possible I'll have to migrate to Windows

---

#### PS

I thought to ask this on Unix-SE but I see that this one has more virtualization questions (and I assume experts!).
But I don't see a dual-boot tag... Strange... The grub tag is the nearest approx I could think of

Comment: The question about where a question is put best is not where you find the most questions about a topic. This site is about business environments. Your question is better suited for [su] or [unix.se].

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use physical harddisk in Virtual Box](https://superuser.com/questions/495025/use-physical-harddisk-in-virtual-box). On a personal and off-topic note; if you're a programming teacher and have used Unix for the past 35 years, you should _really_ get on the virtualisation bandwagon. It's such an essential part of computing nowadays, you really should know at least the basics. Most enterprise applications and this Cloud™ thing run on virtualisation and there are software design considerations to make when your applications run inside VMs.

Comment: @mtak Seems in the direction of what I want... Requires some study! Tnx anyway