# Mount existing partition on VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, windows-8.1, linux-mint

I've been trying to boot my **Windows 8.1** on a **VirtualBox** machine under my **Linux Mint 17**. Everything is in **x64**. I've installed VirtualBox and its GUI to do so. My **Windows 8.1** is on **/dev/sda2**, my **Mint 17** on **/dev/sda3**.

I'm using the command : `VBoxManage internalcommands createrawvmdk -filename ~/.VirtualBox/Eight.vmdk -rawdisk /dev/sda -partitions 2`

Which gives back : `VBoxManage: error: Cannot open the raw disk '/dev/sda': VERR_ACCESS_DENIED [...]`

I'm using http://www.qc4blog.com/?p=483 and [Use VirtualBox to boot a physical drive/partition](https://superuser.com/questions/451573/use-virtualbox-to-boot-a-physical-drive-partition) to get it.

There are many thing said on the net regarding this error. But I'm lost in the middle of them. What should I do to achieve my goal ?

Answer (score 0):

2 things immediately come to mind:

1 Are you running this as root or sudo ? This is needed for raw access to the disk.
 2 Make sure /dev/sda has NONE of it's partitions mounted in Mint. You need VirtualBox to be the ONLY process that accesses the disk on the host OS.